# Xpath to find first occurrence of two different elements

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xpathnavigator

Using the example below, I would like to use xPath to find the first occurence of two different elements. For example, I want to figure out if b or d appears first. We can obviously tell that b appears before d (looking top-down, and not at the tree level). But, how can I solve this using xpath?

```
<a>
   <b>
   </b>
</a>
<c>
</c>
<d>
</d>
```

Right now, I find the node (b and d in this case) by getting the first element in the nodeset, which I find using the following code:

```
String xPathExpression = "//*[local-name()='b']";
XPathNodeIterator nodeSet = (XPathNodeIterator)navigator.Evaluate(xPathExpression);
```

and

```
String xPathExpression = "//*[local-name()='d']";
XPathNodeIterator nodeSet = (XPathNodeIterator)navigator.Evaluate(xPathExpression);
```

Now using xpath, I just can't figure out which comes first, b or d.

Comment: Do you need to do this with xpath?  This can be solved easily with LINQ to XML after the tree is built.

Comment: I'd be open to seeing how this could be done using LINQ to XML. Efficiency is really my only concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to scan the tree in *document order* (the order the elements occur). As though by chance this is the default search order, and all you've got to do is select the first element which is a `<b/>` or `<d/>` node:

```
//*[local-name() = 'b' or local-name() = 'd'][1]
```

If you want the name, add another `local-name(...)` call:

```
local-name(//*[local-name() = 'b' or local-name() = 'd'][1])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to use LINQ to XML to solve the same solution you can try the following:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument(filepath);
XElement first = (from x in xmlDoc.Descendants()
            where x.Name == "b" || x.Name == "d"
            select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now you can run a simple if statement to determine if "b" or "d" was the first element found that matches our criteria.

```
 if(first.Name.Equals("b")
    //code for b being first
 else if(first.Name.Equals("d")
    //code for d being first
```

Per a commentator's suggestion your code would is cleaner to use a lambda expression instead of a full LINQ query, but this can sometimes be confusing if you are new to LINQ.  The following is the exact same query for my `XElement` assignment above:

```
XElement first = xmlDoc.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "b" || x.Name == "d");
```

I hope that's what you're looking for if you were open to not using xpath.

Comment: `xmlDoc.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "b" || x.Name == "d")` seems cleaner, IMO, but is a good alternative.

Comment: That lambda expression does the exact same thing, and yes it is clearer.  However, I wrote the full query out since OP did not request a LINQ answer, so I wanted to provide the full query for reference.  Is that not best practice on SO?

Comment: I'll add that to my answer though.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath expressions would work:

```
//*[local-name()='b' or local-name()='d'][1]
```

Or for a shorter solution, you could try this:

```
(//b|//d)[1]
```

Both expressions will select either `b` elements or `d` elements, in the order in which they appear, and only select the first element from the result set.

Comment: That works in the case I posted above, for sure. But in my actual case, I have these elements at different tree levels, and I also have namespaces in each element name. Thanks for the feedback though, good to know.

Comment: @jsirr13 Sure, I understand this is a sample, but my main goal was to point out that you can use `|` to essentially union two result sets into one (regardless of how they are constructed) then use `(...)[1]` to select the first element in any of those sets.